# Import newly installed site-packages after already setting up a python virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv

I know how to import system site-packages into a **virtual environment** when setting up a virtual environment in python, such as

```
virtualenv venv -p python3 --system-site-packages
```

However, recently I met one problem was that **if I have already set up a virtual environment**, and I have to install a necessary python package through:

```
apt-get install python-package_name
```

those packages **could not be accessed** by the virtual environment that I have already set up before.

Is there any way to do that?